# Change ID in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm having trouble with [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co), how can I change `id` to another field in log file ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate a bit on your problem so we can help you the best we can. Show us your mapping, a sample document, how you ids look like and how you'd like to change them. Anything that can help us understand what you're facing.

Comment: @katy why the bounty if there is an accepted answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the elasticsearch output you can set the document_id for the event you are shipping. This will end up being the _id in elasticsearch. You can use all sort of parameters / field references / ... that are available in logstash config. Like so:

```
elasticsearch { 
    host => yourEsHost
    cluster => "yourCluster"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_id => "%{someFieldOfMyEvent}"
}
```

In this example someFieldOfMyEvent ends up being the _id of this event in ES.

Comment: This really saved the day!